# Using Python Pyadomd Library to get PowerBI Data into Json Format

Tags: python, api, powerbi, azure-active-directory

We have created a API which takes data from PowerBI and provides output in JSON format.

We have made some modifications to the original `pyadomd` code, and it runs without errors. However, it is not displaying the PowerBI data in JSON format as it should.

Original code: https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/.

```py
from sys import path
path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\160')

from pyadomd import Pyadomd
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/Alpino')
def get_data():
    conn_str = 'Provider=MSOLAP;User ID=Alexw@dettol.com;Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/Power BI Model [Test];initial catalog=PBI_Model_20230121;Password=Alexw#2023;Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate;'
    query = """EVALUATE Project"""

    with Pyadomd(conn_str) as conn:
        with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
            data = cur.fetchall()
            print(data)
            return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

For better understanding of **Pyadomd** library, see also the link above.

Output:

[image: Default Comment]

No PowerBI Data are fetched & Return with 404 Error:

[image: No PowerBI Data are fetched & Return with 404 Error]

I think `app.route` is unable to fetch the file path.

When we have used default code it generates Authentication error & after modification now it is not showing output in JSON format. When we mention alpino in url file path it provides 404 error.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes into code & issue has been resolved. Please find below code.

**Python Code :**

```
    from sys import path
path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\160')

from pyadomd import Pyadomd
from flask import Flask, jsonify

# Create a Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Define an API endpoint
@app.route('/alpino')
def alpino():

# Connect to Power BI and execute query
    conn_str = 'Provider=MSOLAP;User ID=Alexw@dettol.com;Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/Power BI Model [Test];initial catalog=PBI_Model_20230121;Password=Alexw#2023;Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate;'
    query = 'EVALUATE ROW("ProjectRowCount",COUNTROWS(Project) )'

    with Pyadomd(conn_str) as conn:
        with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
            data = cur.fetchall()
            column_names = [column[0] for column in cur.description]
            # Convert query result to a list of dictionaries
            result = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in data]
            # Convert the list of dictionaries to a JSON string
            json_result = jsonify(result)
            return json_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Output :**
[Json Output]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYbzy.png

**Query Explanation :**

This code defines a Flask API endpoint that connects to a Power BI data source and executes a query. Here's a step-by-step breakdown of the code:

- The first two lines import the necessary libraries: **sys.path** and **pyadomd** for working with the Power BI data source, and **flask** for building the API endpoint.

> from sys import path
> path.append('\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\160')

> from pyadomd import Pyadomd
> from flask import Flask, jsonify

- The next line creates a Flask app instance with **Flask(name)**.

> app = Flask(name)

- The **@app.route('/alpino')** decorator is used to define the API endpoint. In this case, the endpoint URL is **http:///alpino**.

> @app.route('/alpino')

- The **def alpino():** function defines the behavior of the API endpoint. It first sets up a connection to the Power BI data source with the given connection string and then executes a query using the **Pyadomd** library.

> def alpino():

- The **cur.fetchall()** method retrieves all the data returned by the query.

> with Pyadomd(conn_str) as conn:
> with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
> data = cur.fetchall()

- The column_names variable is set to the list of column names returned by **cur.description**.

> column_names = [column[0] for column in cur.description]

- The **result** variable is set to a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row in the query result. The **zip()** and **dict()** functions are used to map the column names to the row values.

> result = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in data]

- The jsonify() function is used to convert the **result** variable to a JSON string.

> json_result = jsonify(result)

- Finally, the function returns the JSON response using **return json_result**.

> return json_result

In summary, this code sets up a Flask API endpoint that connects to a Power BI data source and returns the result of a query in JSON format. It uses the **pyadomd** library to connect to the data source, and the **flask** library to define the API endpoint and return the JSON response.

#Stay Healthy #Stay Safe
Hope your query got resolved. If you have any query, Feel free to contact us.

|| Jay Hind Jay Bharat ||